# Populate a list in constructor

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function

I'm looking for the better way to initialize a list directly in the constructor of my object. The goal is to put the initialize code at the same place, without taking several many lines.

```
public class Object1
{
    public string data1 { get; set; }
    public string data2 { get; set; }
    public List<Object2> myList { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string myData { get; set; }
}

public class Object3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string myOtherData { get; set; }
}
```

There is my way in order to initialize myList from Objet1 :

```
public static void myProgram()
{
    List<Object3> test = new List<Object3>
    {
        new Object3
        {
            Id = 1,
            myOtherData = "blabla"
        },
                    new Object3
        {
            Id = 8,
            myOtherData = "blabla"
        }
    };

    /* That is what I do now */
    Object1 myObject = new Object1
    {
        data1 = "toto",
        data2 = "titi",
        myList = test != null && test.Count > 0 ? new List<Object2>() : null
    };

    foreach (Object3 obj3 in test)
    {
        if (obj3.Id > 3)
        {
            myObject.myList.Add(new Object2
            {
                Id = obj3.Id,
                myData = $"lol {obj3.myOtherData}"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way which avoid to use a foreach after construction of my object. Something like this :

```
/* That is what I try to do */
Object1 myObject = new Object1
{
    data1 = "toto",
    data2 = "titi",
    myList = test != null && test.Count > 0 ? new List<Object2>().AddRange( /* PUT THE FOREACH HERE */)
}
```

I think we can use lambda / delegates in order to create anonymous function which will fill the list, but I don't how it works.
}

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Linq.

```
myList = test?.Where(x => x.Id > 3).Select(x => new Object2
{
    Id = x.Id,
    myData = $"lol {x.myOtherData}"
}).ToList()
```

Comment: If OP wants an empty collection in case `test` is null apppend `?? new List<Object2>()`